# how to install web socket on my host?

Tags: html, websocket

I want to install websocket in my host,

How can I do that?

is there any guide to show how to install websocket on the host?

many thanks.

Comment: Review: http://davidwalsh.name/websocket

Comment: Thanks . I will check it maybe I should add the line `<script src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review:

[david walsh - websocket](http://davidwalsh.name/websocket)

Socket.io you can use and integrate with Express, which is a framework for Nodejs.

[socket.io - how-to-use](http://socket.io/#how-to-use)

I hope it helps somewhat.

Regards.